# Concealing an RDP service with a website

Tags: security, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

Is there a way (using a proxy or otherwise) to conceal an RDP service listening on port 443, such that HTTPS requests made from a browser serve a website while RDP requests connect as normal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Windows Server comes with a role called "Remote Desktop Gateway," or RD Gateway, formerly known as Terminal Services Gateway. It essentially behaves exactly as you've described, though I'd personally be hesitant to use the word 'conceal.' It is just an RPC/HTTP(S) proxy.

In past deployments, I would often make the default web page say what this service was and how to use the RDP client to leverage this gateway, etc.

```
You --- (TCP 443) ---> RD Gateway --- (TCP 3389) ---> Internal Computer
```

[image: MSTSC RD Gateway Settings]

Comment: Thank you - can you please add a reference as to how to customize the welcome page? Also, is it possible to connect to the gateway itself through port 443 (connect to the gateway through itself?)?

Comment: @georgiosd It is the default IIS web site, so you would just navigate to C:\inetpub\wwwroot and edit the file default.aspx (or whatever your default document is) and actually change/write the HTML in that file. As for the second question, I've never seen anything like that, but what you could do to make things as easy as possible for your users, is supply a *.rdp file as a download on your front page that contains the settings for your gateway.

Comment: The intention here is to conceal the RDP endpoint from someone that is .e.g port scanning and wants to try breaking in. If you can misdirect them by serving a static page over SSL, it would lead them to think it's a normal web server instead of an RDP gateway.

Comment: That's cool, you can put anything you want on the web page... something like <h1>Go away, hacker...</h1>

Comment: LOL. Right - but the question is not whether you can conceal port 80 but port 443 which is on the gateway. perhaps someone else can chime in!

Comment: I am only talking about port 443.  443 is the only port open in this scenario.

Comment: So just to clarify - in this config, IIS will serve HTML content on 443 if a browser connects but RDP will take over if an RDP Client connects?

Comment: Correct. . . . .

Comment: Awesome! I just need to test whether I can use the same server as RDP gateway and server then.